Texas instruments MSP boot
I would like to ask if it is possible to start the BSL code of the MSP430F5 series, which resides at location 0x1000, before the user main code always, or if it is always required to call it from the user code.
The BSL works when it is invoked from usercode. I cannot use external pins so it is not an option for me.

Please refer this discussion: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/120536/custom-reset-vector/429020#429020
And link to new slau132r: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau132r/slau132r.pdf
